# error converting datatype conversion on single vendoritemnumber in duplicate rows

Tags: sql-server

Sql server query shows error :

```
Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Line 1
Error converting data type varchar to numeric.
```

Here is the query:

```
    WITH employee AS (
SELECT distinct vendoritemnumber,VendorItemId,
VendorItemDescription,
VendorItemDescriptionAlias,VendorId,BrgItemId,itemconversionFactor,
orderbyuomid,pricebyuomid,vendorcasedescription,manufacturernumber,skunumber,[weight],
averageweight,currentprice,taxable,[status],createddate,inactivedate,lastpurchaseddate,
lastupdatedby,lastupdateddate,vendorpercent,vendorfreight,brandid,pack,size,inventorycategoryid,
binlocation,inventorylocation,inventorystatus,physicalinventoryconversionfactor,stateswhereused,
conceptwhereused,priceupdatedate,size_uom,pack_uom,isdeleted,'' as id,'' itemid,'' as oldprice,
'' as newprice,'' as dateupdated,'' as weekenddate,'' as lastpurdate
FROM VendorItems WHERE BrgItemId=6056)
SELECT * FROM employee 
UNION ALL 
SELECT '' as ven,v.VendorItemId,
v.VendorItemDescription,v.VendorItemDescriptionAlias,v.VendorId,v.BrgItemId,v.itemconversionFactor,
v.orderbyuomid,v.pricebyuomid,v.vendorcasedescription,v.manufacturernumber,v.skunumber,v.[weight],
v.averageweight,v.currentprice,v.taxable,v.[status],v.createddate,v.inactivedate,v.lastpurchaseddate,
v.lastupdatedby,v.lastupdateddate,v.vendorpercent,v.vendorfreight,v.brandid,v.pack,v.size,v.inventorycategoryid,
v.binlocation,v.inventorylocation,v.inventorystatus,v.physicalinventoryconversionfactor,v.stateswhereused,
v.conceptwhereused,v.priceupdatedate,v.size_uom,v.pack_uom,v.isdeleted,ph.id,ph.itemid,ph.oldprice,
ph.newprice,ph.dateupdated,ph.weekenddate,brg.lastpurchasedate
from [dbo].[VendorItems] v join PriceHistory ph
on ph.ItemId=v.VendorItemId join brgitems brg on
brg.brgitemid=v.BrgItemId
WHERE v.BrgItemId=6056
group by vendoritemnumber,v.VendorItemId,v.VendorItemDescription,v.VendorItemDescriptionAlias,v.VendorId,v.BrgItemId,v.itemconversionFactor,
v.orderbyuomid,v.pricebyuomid,v.vendorcasedescription,v.manufacturernumber,v.skunumber,v.[weight],
v.averageweight,v.currentprice,v.taxable,v.[status],v.createddate,v.inactivedate,v.lastpurchaseddate,
v.lastupdatedby,v.lastupdateddate,v.vendorpercent,v.vendorfreight,v.brandid,v.pack,v.size,v.inventorycategoryid,
v.binlocation,v.inventorylocation,v.inventorystatus,v.physicalinventoryconversionfactor,v.stateswhereused,
v.conceptwhereused,v.priceupdatedate,v.size_uom,v.pack_uom,v.isdeleted,ph.id,ph.itemid,ph.oldprice,
ph.newprice,ph.dateupdated,ph.weekenddate,brg.lastpurchasedate
```

I want to show single vendoritemnumber in duplicate rows..Any suggestion??
Where is the error??

Comment: I'm guessing vendoritemnumber is a numeric data type. If that's the case, the select after the union all should not start with `'' as ven,`. Try `null as ven,` instead.

Answer (score 2):

SQL Server cannot convert an empty string to `NUMERIC` data type. For example, the following will yield the same error:

```
SELECT CONVERT(NUMERIC, '')
```

Replace empty strings (`''`) with `0` or `NULL`.

Comment: now showing 3 rows bcoz union all but i want 2 rows and this is actual return data. so please help me.

Comment: @ManojMaharana, what do you mean? Is it a duplicate row? If so, change `UNION ALL` to `UNION`

Answer (score 0):

@manoj .Just FYI to know exact error point , double click on the error in message window .It shows the exact line of code on error, Also try to check if any empty values are there for that column and as mentioned by @Serge SQL throws error while any data type is converted to numeric and if  its value is empty. Best solution is to add WHERE clause and filter those cases.